# Function executing a Bash script not working ("No such file or directory")

Tags: bash, function, alias

So, I wrote a function to execute a Bash script just to circumvent taking my sweet time to navigate to the directory of that script.

However, when I launch the function (via an alias), Bash tells me there's no such file or directory! It's nuts!

Here's the function in question:

```
function torBrowser()
{
    echo "Running Tor browser..."
    bash "/home/user/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser.sh"
}
```

The access modes for the script and the parent directories are all rwxr-xr-x, so, technically, it should work with a couple of tweaks here and there somewhere.

Comment: Could you show us how you call that function?

Comment: Sure. I'm using an alias, which I initialized like so: `alias torbrowse=torBrowser` I just type `torbrowse` in the shell.

Comment: Any chance the error is coming from the script itself, perhaps it assumes you're in that directory, i.e. try something like `cd /home/user/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US && bash start-tor-broswer.sh`

Comment: Can you share the error message? Usually if `bash` gives that error, it tells you what the name was that it couldn't find.

Comment: Add `set -x` as the first line of the function.  Then consider `bash -x "/home/..."`.  The former probably won't tell you anything much (but could be considered 'start at the beginning'); the latter is rather more likely to reveal the inner secrets of where the failure occurs.

Comment: I've tried all the recommended changes so far, but they all keep returning the same error, which is: `bash: /home/user/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser.sh: No such file or directory` The script itself does work when I launch it in its directory.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing obviously wrong with that. I recreated it here and it worked for me. It's got to be a typo or something. If you do `$ls /home/user/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser.sh` do you get an error? You are replacing "user" with your actually user name, right? :)